# UV mesh does not appear in UV editor in blender 2.8 but does in 2.79

Tags: uv

as you can see in the below images, when I try to view the UV mesh in the UV editor In blender 2.79 It works perfectly, but when I open the exact same file in blender 2.8 It does not show up. I have already checked the "view" menu which only shows the options for "view" "mask" and "paint" and not "UV".
[image: I can view the UV mesh in 2.79]

[image: But not in 2.8]

I have also tried this with a new object in a new file and that doesn't work either
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2.80 the Image and UV Editors are 2 different things.

Your screenshot is showing you have the Image Editor open.

Change to UV Editor to see the UV unwraps :

[image]